# SyntaxError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

When I test my game in Adobe Flash CC, I get this error: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

This is basically the code around the error (I removed the unimportant parts to make it clearer):

```
package ui.levelSelect {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class LevelsContainer extends MovieClip {

        public var levelThumbs:Array;
        public var levels:Array = [{name:'level1'},{name:'level2'}];

        public function LevelsContainer(){

            for(var i:String in levels) {
                var index:int = int(index);

                levelThumbs[index] = new MovieClip; //This is the line where I get the error

            }

        }



    }

}
```

What causes this error? `levelThumbs` is already declared right? Changing it to `this.levelThumbs` doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declaring a variable does not allocate any memory for the object, and thus have the value null. You have to actually allocate memory for `levelThumbs` array by calling `new Array` or `[]`.

```
public var levelThumbs:Array = new Array;
```

or

```
public var levelThumbs:Array = [];
```

Comment: It is the right answer but the explanation is erroneous for 2 reasons, the process described is not allocation of memory but creation of class instance. To create an instance of a class (here Array) memory must be allocated. Memory allocation does not equal class instance creation. Finally creating instances at declaration time is also not recommended. Those objects will be instantiated before he object itself. Instead create your object inside your constructor.